# I created a dataframe using pyspark but cannot view the data created

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark

I created a dataframe using pyspark but cannot view the data created using `.show()` I'll get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\user\Documents\Python Programming\PySpark_for_Big_Data.ipynb Cell 20 line 1
----> 1 ds.show()

File C:\spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:945, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    885 def show(self, n: int = 20, truncate: Union[bool, int] = True, vertical: bool = False) -> None:
    886     """Prints the first ``n`` rows to the console.
    887 
    888     .. versionadded:: 1.3.0
   (...)
    943     name | Bob
    944     """
--> 945     print(self._show_string(n, truncate, vertical))

File C:\spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:963, in DataFrame._show_string(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    957     raise PySparkTypeError(
    958         error_class="NOT_BOOL",
    959         message_parameters={"arg_name": "vertical", "arg_type": type(vertical).__name__},
    960     )
    962 if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 963     return self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical)
    964 else:
    965     try:
...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:386)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
    ... 26 more
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

In my Local Disk, spark folder contains a `spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3` folder which is the spark version.
I also used `pip install pyspark` to install pyspark in terminal

My Environment Variables settings are:
HADOOP_HOME: `C:\hadoop` which contains a `winutils` file version 3

SPARK_HOME: `C:\spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3`

JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20`

SPARK_LOCAL_IP: `127.0.0.1`

PYTHONPATH: `%SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip`

PATH: `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin`
`%SPARK_HOME%\bin`

Software versions are:
My Java Version: `java 20.0.2 2023-07-18`

My Python version: `Python 3.12.0`

My Spark version: `Spark 3.5.1`

Python Kernel used in VS Code IDE: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe`

Please advise. I am desperate.

Comment: *Error Index out of range* at `[0]` indicates an empty list, which means the glob attempt from `findspark.init()` has failed: zip file was not found. What about SPARK_HOME config? What is the real location of that zip file, i.e. where have you saved it upon download?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How come PySpark can't find my SPARK\_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250687/how-come-pyspark-cant-find-my-spark-home)
Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63572803/12846804 (although no accepted answer in that one)

Comment: Spark runs on Java 8/11/17. See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/